# stop accessing a page directly, redirect always

Tags: php, redirect

got a link in a.php to b.php
there is a link in b.php to a third party page( like 'paypal')

if user click back from third party page it take you to b.php

want to avoid that and skip to a.php

tried http_referer which is always a.php

its similar to a typical shopping cart.
user add items to cart in a.php then click 'payment' which takes them to b.php, which is T&C and a checkbox to agree to it.

never want user to directly browse b.php

Comment: One way would be set a `$_SESSION` var, and do the redirection using that

Answer (score 3):

Assign session in php A

```
$_SESSION['hi'] = 1;
```

And check session if it is available in php B then remove it at the end of your code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['hi'])){
//your code
unset($_SESSION['hi']);
}else{
//redirect somewhere
}
```

Comment: this works fine if somebody refresh b.php
but when clicking browser back button, it wont handle it.

Comment: after reading  feature of browser back button and caching of page, I realized  this needs to be handled in a different way.